# covert dynamic web page to static in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**I generate dynamic web pages using next js and react js. I generate some web pages about users, when user data get changed I want to get static HTML web page from that. How I do this process in next js, is there any external or built-in Library for this task**

I use,
React js,Next js, and Hooks for my entire project

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for static HTML export which is part of Next.js out of the box. See the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Answer (score 0):

If understood well, you like to have server side rendering, and next js has some stuff for it.

```
import React from "react";

export async function getServerSideProps() {
 //some server side stuff, example: API calls
}

//you can use function, class etc. instead of const
const test = () => {
 return (
 <div>123<div>
 )
}

export default test;
```

Please, read some documentation about getServerSideProps [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)